# Date/Number ranges displaying incorrectly

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a 3rd party "shopping cart" program (CartWeaver) that uses a MySQL database.  The products in my store have primary and secondary categories, the latter of which where my issue lies.
I am using date ranges (e.g. 1930-1939, 1940-1949, etc), however when I view the ranges on the product search page, the first number sequence is displaying incorrectly. For example, the date range 1930-1939 is displaying as 3860-1930, and 1940-1949 is displaying as 3880-1949 (you can see the issue at www.silverscreencollectibles.com/searchpage.php).
I have tried multiple variables to try to get around this, all to no available.  Here is what I've tried: Starting the sequence with an alpha character, starting it with a special character, putting the range in single as well as double quotes, putting a space between the sequences, replacing the dash with the alpha "to". I have also deleted and recreated the subcategories, and nothing I have tried changes the result. The entry for "2000-Present" also displays incorrectly (as 4000-Present).
I'm just a dumb user, not a programmer, so any responses that anyone is kind enough to  offer will need to be "dumbed down".  The application support group wants me to either send them my entire database, or allow them to directly access my site...and neither option appeals to me, from a security standpoint.  I thought I would throw the issue out to the StackOverFlow community to see if anyone has seen this sort of issue before, and may be able to point me in the right direction to address the issue.  Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Please paste some code here

Comment: Maybe you're making some numeric operation to your data before it's displayed without knowing. Can you provide some code?

Comment: Indeed, we would need the code that 1° fetches the data from the database (without passwords and such); 2° generates the dropdown list.

Comment: I'm not sure I know enough to help you, help me
Below is the PHP that looks like it calls the Subcategory info, (file 2 large 2 post)

// show secondary categories 
if(!isset($module_settings["show_empty"])) { $module_settings["show_empty"] = $_ENV["application.cw"]["appDisplayEmptyCategories"]; }
// show secondary categories 
if(!isset($module_settings["show_secondary"])) { $module_settings["show_secondary"] = true; }
// relate secondary categories to primary cats 
if(!isset($module_settings["relate_cats"])) { $module_settings["relate_cats"] = $_ENV["application.cw"]["appEnableCatsRelated"];